# Error in Update T-SQL in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to update some data in EditEmail table from DBUsers database to EditEmail  table in DBCurrent datebase.So i got error when  i execute following statement:

```
USE DBCurrent

UPDATE [DBUsers].[dbo].[EditEmail] EN
SET EN.MailSubject = E.MailSubject,
    EN.MailMessage = E.MailMessage
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM EditEmail
) AS E
WHERE EN.Type = E.Type
```

Error message:

> ```
> ERROR:
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'EN'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
> ```

Is there any syntax  mistake in this T-SQL?

Comment: I think you have some problem, when there are more than one emails of any given Type. The update will coppy the values of one of them to the other table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give the table you're specifying in the `UPDATE` statement a table alias (for whatever reason - don't ask me why this isn't possible, ask the T-SQL design team)...

Try this statement instead:

```
USE DBCurrent

UPDATE 
    [DBUsers].[dbo].[EditEmail] 
SET 
    MailSubject = E.MailSubject,
    MailMessage = E.MailMessage
FROM
    dbo.EditEmail E
WHERE 
    DBUsers.dbo.EditEmail.Type = E.Type
    AND E.Type = 'blahblah'  -- or whatever additional conditions you have!
```

You need to specify the table being updated in full, e.g. with its database, schema, table and column name, in the `WHERE` clause.

There is also no need for your "artificial" subquery there to reference the `EditMail` table - just define that in the `FROM` clause and give it a table alias (here, they're supported).

Comment: Thanks for reply.one more thing is what would be the syntax if i want to apply some condition on dbo.EditEmail E (i.e.FROM  dbo.EditEmail E WHERE Type = 'blahblah..')

Comment: @Sukhi: just add ` AND E.Type = 'blahblah'` to that WHERE clause  that's there. Updated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL doesn't allow to define an alias on the table updated, 
but it allows to update an alias:

This fixes the syntax, I think the logic must still be improved.
Please try (I didn't check):

```
UPDATE EN
SET EN.MailSubject = E.MailSubject,
    EN.MailMessage = E.MailMessage
FROM [DBUsers].[dbo].[EditEmail] EN
    join EditEmail E
on EN.Type = E.Type
```